# Read Exif thumbnail from JPEG file

Tags: c++, qt, exif

Is it possible to access the Exif thumbnail of a JPEG file using *only Qt 5.8 functionality* and not an external library?

Comment: Given that `libjpeg` itself is written in C, the answer should be pretty obvious...

Comment: `libjpeg` is an extarnal library. Does Qt itself provide such functionality? (By C++ or C I meant that I don't search for a Python etc. solution.)

Comment: maybe this will help you -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286662/is-there-any-sample-code-to-read-thumbnail-from-jpeg-exif-header

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128656/read-exif-metadata-of-images-in-qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to import the old Nokia times sources when there was a Qt Extended module, with classes like [QExifImageHeader](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtextended4.4/qexifimageheader.html), which had a [thumbnail()](https://github.com/FilipBE/qtextended/blob/master/src/libraries/qtopia/qexifimageheader.cpp#L1316) method. See also [QTBUG-9414](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-9414)

Comment: So this means that Qt 5.8 does not provide a way to extract the Exif thumbnail _by itself_?

Comment: Qt doesn't do everything. That's why specialized libraries/classes exist. It's like asking if Qt does FFT. Answer: no.

Comment: There is a objection. You did mention that Qt 4.4 did provide a way. I don't care if Qt does the work itself or if it uses libjpeg.

Comment: Objection rejected. Qt extended was not part of the Qt framework. It was an external module provided only in the Qtopia project when Nokia attempted to build phones with an OS based on Qt. In any case **I did** provided an answer which uses **only Qt functionality** so you should accept/vote it. If you're afraid to drag 1 additional class in your project, then it's another story.